# Слитное/раздельное написание производных предлогов

Tags: орфография, предлоги, слитно-раздельно

Извиняюсь, если здесь уже было об этом рассказано, но я, по крайне мере, не нашёл.
Есть какое-то общее правило слитного/раздельного написания производных предлогов?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, существует ли какое "правило", но на практике проще выучить несколько случаев слитного написания: **вроде, наподобие, ввиду, насчёт, вследствие**. Эти производные предлоги пишутся слитно. Из употребительных это, пожалуй, все.  Остальные пишутся раздельно.

Никаких явных причин для слитного написания перечисленных при раздельном написании остальных я не вижу. То есть это скорее всего более традиция, чем мотивированные исключения.

Не знаю, что тут еще добавить. Разве что кто-то еще "исключения" вспомнит.

(+)
Есть, конечно, огромное число слитно пишущихся производных предлогов типа "предлог+существительное" (сбоку, посередине, вместо и т. д.), в которых существительное полностью утратило свое лексическое значение, но они трудностей не должны вызывать.